# Inverse function of a taylor expansion

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

If I have this equation

$$r(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{12}-\frac{t^3}{720}+\mathcal{O}(t^5)$$

Is there any possibility to find $t(r)$?

Comment: No.  $r$ is not completely specified.  Infinitely many functions satisfy that equation.

Comment: Suppose that $r \in [0,1]$

Comment: You can find approximation by ignoring the $O(t^5)$ term and solving the cubic.

Comment: @herbsteinberg this would help me a lot!

Comment: Are you actually trying to find an inverse function, as stated in the title, or do you want an approximation?

Comment: @saulspatz Also an approximation would help me...I thought first to find a direct inverse function.

Comment: @You'l have to settle for an approximation, since we only know $r$ approximately.  Just ignore the error term.

Comment: @saulspatz okay... an answer with any hint or complete solution would be great

Comment: Do you know about [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)?

Comment: It is likely that what you really want is the first few terms of the Taylor expansion of the local inverse at the point $(0,1/2)$. This is an skill that is common in introductions to calculus. Is that what is needed? The idea would be to apply the chain rule and use the property that composing $r$ with its inverse gives you the identity. That formula you were linked to (Lagrange's) is what you would get in general. Learning the formula is quite unimportant, but knowing how to find it is within what you should know.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas No :-(

Comment: It's a cubic, so you could use Cardano's formula, but that's hardly worth the trouble.  I would solve it numerically, using any one of numerous computer tools.  Type it into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+r+%3D+1%2F2%2Bt%2F12-t%5E3%2F720), for example.  That's probably not what you want, but if you have a particular value of $r$ in mind, like $.7,$ you'll do a [lot better](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+.7+%3D+1%2F2%2Bt%2F12-t%5E3%2F720)

Comment: r=0.49 for example

Comment: @Melina What saulspatz is suggesting is probably the worse approach to your question.

Comment: @noodlesGroup Okay, I am not sure if I understood what you said in previous comment.

Comment: Look in the link that Prasun gave you. If $t(x)$ is the inverse (in a neighborhood of $(0,1/2)$), then $x=r(t(x))$. We want to compute the Taylor series of $t(x)$ at $x=1/2$. So, a series that looks like $t(1/2)+t'(1/2)(x-1/2)+t''(1/2)(x-1/2)^2/2+...$ Taking derivatives in $x=r(t(x))$ you get $1=r'(t(x))t'(x)$. Evaluate at $x=1/2$. This gives $1=r'(t(1/2))t'(1/2)=r'(0)t'(1/2)$. From the given Taylor expansion you can tell that $r'(0)=1/12$. Therefore, $t'(1/2)=12$. Taking more derivatives of $1=r'(t(x))t'(x)$ and applying the chain rul you can find higher and higher derivatives of $t(x)$ ...

Comment: ... and form its Taylor series as long as the derivatives of $r(t)$ are in the given Taylor. This is equivalent to the formulas Prasun linked. Once you form the (beginning of the) Taylor series of $t(x)$ at $x=1/2$, then you can use it to approximate values like $t(0.49)$ under the assumption that $0.49$ is close enough to $1/2=0.5$.

Comment: @noodlesGroup I appreciate this... maybe you should write as an answer to get more points!

Comment: @Melina Or better, you can complete the computation and write it. That way you make sure you understood.

Comment: @noodlesGroup I couldn't find the rest of the terms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a suitable Computer Algebra System such as Mathematica to invert the powers series gives $t(r) = 12(r-\frac12) +\frac{144}5(r-\frac12)^3+\mathcal{O}(r-\frac12)^5\;$-- the best answer given the original information. 
The Mathematica command is $\texttt{InverseSeries[ 1/2 + t/12 - t^3/720 + O[t]^5, r]}$.

But this example is so simple you don't need a CAS to solve it. It is easy to see that the answer is $t(r)=c_1(r-\frac12) +c_3(r-\frac12)^3+\mathcal{O}(r-\frac12)^5\;$ for some constants $c_1,c_3.\;$ Now from the given equation we get $\;r(t)-\frac12 = \frac{t}{12} - \frac{t^3}{720}+\mathcal{O}{(t^5)},\;$ and so $\;12(r(t)-\frac12) = t - \frac{t^3}{60}+\mathcal{O}{(t^5)}\;$ and $c_1=12.\;$ Similarly, one more step gives $\;c_3=12^3\frac1{60}=\frac{144}5.$